# Adding or removing a new route to the routeProvider, it doesn't load anything in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, angularjs-ng-route

I have this website routing my pages with 4 html files and it works fine, but when I am trying to add or remove a new one, it just shows blank screen with my navigation bar only.
The error I caught is : 
Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error

Being a noobie in Angular I saw various solutions that have to do with the ngRoute, but in vain.

I want to add more html files for the rest of the projects but I can't.

I use 1.2.15 version and call the files locally. Below is the Angular script I am using, there's also some code added to browse through the projects.

```
            var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate']);

            app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, NextBackBasicService, $location) {
              $scope.message = $location.path();
            });

            app.config(function($routeProvider) {
              $routeProvider.
              when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'home.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
                    }).
              when('/example1', {
                templateUrl: 'example.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
              }).
              when('/example2', {
                templateUrl: 'example2.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
              }).
              when('/example3', {
                templateUrl: 'example3.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
              }).
              when('/example4', {
                templateUrl: 'example4.html',
                controller: 'MainCtrl'
              });
              $routeProvider.otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/route'
              });
            });

            app.run(function($rootScope, NextBackBasicService){
              $rootScope.goNext = function() {
                NextBackBasicService.goNext();
              };

              $rootScope.goBack = function() {
                NextBackBasicService.goBack();
              };
            });

            app.factory('NextBackBasicService', function($route, $location) {
              //array for keeping defined routes
              var routes = [];

              angular.forEach($route.routes, function(config, route) {
                //not to add same route twice
                if (angular.isUndefined(config.redirectTo)) {
                  routes.push(route);
                }
              });

              return {
                goNext: function() {
                  var nextIndex = routes.indexOf($location.path()) + 1;
                  if (nextIndex === routes.length) {
                    $location.path(routes[0]);
                  } else {
                    $location.path(routes[nextIndex]);
                  }
                },
                goBack: function() {
                  //window.history.back();
                  var backIndex = routes.indexOf($location.path()) - 1;
                  if (backIndex === -1) {
                    $location.path(routes[routes.length - 1]);
                  } else {
                    $location.path(routes[backIndex]);
                  }
                }
              };

            });
```

And here is my index.html

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html ng-app="myapp">

              <head>
                <meta charset="utf-8" />
                <title>My Title</title>
                 <!--<script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.15"></script>
                <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.15"></script>-->
                <!--<script data-require="ng-route@*" data-semver="1.2.0" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.0-rc.3/angular-route.js"></script>-->
                <!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.13/angular-animate.js"></script>
                  <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
                -->
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
                <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
                <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700&subset=latin,greek,greek-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
                <!--Loads Angular
                <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.15"></script>
                <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular-route.min.js" data-semver="1.2.15"></script>
                <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>-->

                <script src="js/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.15"></script>
                <script src="js/angular-route.min.js" data-semver="1.2.15"></script>
                <script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
                <script src="app.js"></script>

                <!--jQuery-->
                <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">
                <!--Bootstrap-->
                <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
                <script>
                    $( document ).ready(function() {
                        $(".burger").click(function(){
                             $(this).toggleClass("active");
                        });
                    });
                </script>
              </head>

              <body>

                  <!-- Navigation -->
                <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
                    <div class="container mynavigation">
                        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                            <!--<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            </button>-->
                            <button type="button" class="burger navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                                <span></span>
                            </button>

                            <a class="pull-left" href="#">
                                <img class="logodimensions" src="images/svg/logo.svg" alt="">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li>
                                   <a class="animlinks" href="#">WORK</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                   <a class="animlinks" href="#">CONTACT / ABOUT</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.container -->
                </nav>

                <div class="grids">
                <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
                <ng-view></ng-view>
             </div>
             </div>

              </body>

            </html>
```

And bellow is the home where the routing takes place between the projects.

```
            <div class="container">

              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-6 zeromarginpadding">
                  <div class="thumbnail zeromarginpadding">
                     <a href="#/example1">
                         <div class="caption">
                            <p class="thumbnail-text-title">Cards</p>
                            <p class="thumbnail-text-descr">Project subtitle</p>
                        </div>  
                    </a>
                    <img class="imagethumb" src="" alt="...">
                  </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-6 zeromarginpadding">
                  <div class="thumbnail zeromarginpadding">
                     <a href="#/example2">
                         <div class="caption">
                            <p class="thumbnail-text-title">Cards</p>
                            <p class="thumbnail-text-descr">Project subtitle</p>
                        </div>  
                    </a>
                    <img class="imagethumb" src="" alt="...">
                  </div>
                </div>

                 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-6 zeromarginpadding">
                  <div class="thumbnail zeromarginpadding">
                     <a href="#/example3">
                         <div class="caption">
                            <p class="thumbnail-text-title">Cards</p>
                            <p class="thumbnail-text-descr">Project subtitle</p>
                        </div>  
                    </a>
                    <img class="imagethumb" src="" alt="...">
                  </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-lg-3 col-xs-6 zeromarginpadding">
                  <div class="thumbnail zeromarginpadding">
                     <a href="#/example4">
                         <div class="caption">
                            <p class="thumbnail-text-title">Cards</p>
                            <p class="thumbnail-text-descr">Project subtitle</p>
                        </div>  
                    </a>
                    <img class="imagethumb" src="" alt="...">
                  </div>
                </div>


              </div>



            </div>
```

Comment: Post the full error.

Comment: Hi matmo, the error in the console is the following : 

angular.min.js:32 
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=r255&p1=ReferenceE…0at%20Uc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fr255%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A215)

Comment: Failed to instantiate module r255 due to:
ReferenceError: when is not defined
at http://localhost/r255/app.js:29:5
at Object.d [as invoke] (http://localhost/r255/js/angular.min.js:33:335)
at http://localhost/r255/js/angular.min.js:32:196
at Array.forEach (native)
at r (http://localhost/r255/js/angular.min.js:7:280)
at e (http://localhost/r255/js/angular.min.js:32:9)
at Zb (http://localhost/r255/js/angular.min.js:35:98)
at c (http://localhost/r255/js/angular.min.js:17:431)
at Yb (http://localhost/r255/js/angular.min.js:18:140)
at Uc (http://localhost/r255/js/angular.min.js:17:215

Comment: Can you post the first error inside of backticks (\`) Like `this` ? That way it won't ruin the url. You should be able to visit the url and it will basically tell you what the issue is. injector:modulerr usually means there was a problem loading your modules. It looks like the reason is a 'ReferenceError', but I can't view the full error since the url you posted is mangled.

Comment: `http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=r255&p1=TypeError%…0at%20Uc%20(http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fr255%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A215)`

Comment: Theres stil a '...' in the url, which is hiding most of the important information.

Comment: It's actually like this in the link, with the three dots. If I remove them it displays a different solution.

Comment: Yeah, its telling you theres a TypeError at "..." , and the "..." is hiding the most important information - its telling you where the TypeError is. I assume wherever you're copying it from doesn't have the ..., but its being shortened somewhere along the copy+paste process.

Comment: It actually displays the link in the console with the three dots. If I remove them it's like this 
`https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=r255&p1=TypeError%0At%20Uc%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fr255%2Fjs%2Fangular.min.js:17:215)`

Comment: Hmmm...well it seems like you have a TypeError somewhere, according to the error. Try commenting out the app.config() block and see if the error still occurs. Also, it wouldn't hurt to upgrade to a newer version of angular - 1.2 is pretty old.

Comment: If I comment the app.config() block I receive no error in the console.
Also, you are right about the version but this is an old project and that's why I haven't updated it and I'm afraid that if I do, it might ruin it.
Maybe a screenshot could help you?
http://oi66.tinypic.com/wbymog.jpg

Comment: That is weird...not sure how $routeProvider could be undefined there. For the heck of it, try removing that last reference to $routeProvider and just chain the .otherwise() call onto previous .when() call, like so: `.when('/example4', {
        templateUrl: 'example4.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/route'
    });`

Comment: Hi matmo, it worked! Jesus, what could be the cause?
Thank you very much!!

Comment: Nice. I have no idea what would cause it to be undefined...that seems impossible, actually, lol. Maybe set a breakpoint there in your dev tools and inspect the variable at that point. Anyways, I posted my recommendation above as an answer if you feel like accepting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the posted error, the last reference to $routeProvider is undefined. There seems to be something odd going on, because that shouldn't be possible. To side-step this issue though, you can remove the last reference to $routeProvider and just chain the .otherwise() call onto the previous .when() call, like so:

`.when('/example4', { templateUrl: 'example4.html', controller: 'MainCtrl' }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/route' });`